# Is there a way to pivot/transpose data in python the same way that tableau pivots data?

Tags: python, pivot, tableau-api, transpose

I really like the way that tableau pivots data but I have a very large dataset and I'd like to do this same function but in python. I'm hoping this will lighten the load on tableau to help it run more efficiently but I'm not sure how to do this in python. It seems like transpose would be a good place to start but I'm not sure how it would work.

Answer (score 1):

Are you working in Pandas? You likely want to be

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html